# field-validator: How to set actual date as max date?

Tags: validation, struts2, field

I want to put the actual day as the maximum Date.
How can in realize this? No Idea :(

```
<field name="publishment">
    <field-validator type="date">
          <param name="max"> *actual Date* </param>
          <message key="exception.pubPublishment" />
      </field-validator>        
</field>
```

Comment: What do you mean by *actual*? Do you mean current date `now`?

Comment: current date... but i gave up on this and implemented an exception in the action

Answer (score 1):

If you want to set current date as max date range in `date` validator use `maxExpression` parameter instead of `max`. And you can create new `java.util.Date` object for validating with current date.

```
<field name="publishment">
    <field-validator type="date">
          <param name="maxExpression">${new java.util.Date()}</param>
          <message key="exception.pubPublishment" />
      </field-validator>        
</field>
```

Comment: @user2182326: What exactly are you entering? What version of Struts2?

Comment: 01.01.2020 and the field is an textfield, guess that was the problem ?

Comment: @user2182326: You need a converter to convert date string in that format to date object. Anyway this answer is correct one, accept/upvote it for future references.